# Web Api Serialization or Deserialization issue

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I am calling my Web Api controller from my service. My model object is passed correctly, but in the controller my object navigation property is missing.

Here is my model structure

```
public class ClassA
{
    public String PropA { get; set; }
    public String PropB  { get; set; }
    public virtual ClassB PropClassB { get; set; }
}

public class ClassB
{
    public string PropC { get; set; }
    public bool PropD { get; set; }
}
```

and my method which is calling controller is

```
private void publishReport(T perameter)
{
    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GovernmentApiBaseUrl"]);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsJsonAsync<T>(_apiUrl, perameter).Result; // here I have a value in navigation property
    }
}
```

And here is my controller

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage PublishPOBReport([FromBody] ClassA parameter) // here parameter have all the values but the navigation property is null
{
    return new HttpResponseMessage() { StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK };
}
```

Comment: can you confirm that json contains `ClassB`? I had some issues with `native .net json serializer <-> Json.NET` (Web API uses as default) communication, so try to use Json.NET on both sides.

Comment: Above code work perfect (can Serialization or Deserialization nav property) at my machine, I think problem not lies on above code.

Comment: I highly doubt that you get records from EF using lazy loading feature, try to fetch record using [Eagerly Loading](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx) and check again at your end

Comment: i am using Eager loading using entity.include()

Comment: you can share more details, cause above code doesn't break in general scenario and I hope you passed ClassA instead of T in  client.PostAsJsonAsync<T>(_apiUrl, perameter).Result.

Comment: yes i am passing T but but actually in publishReport its also T i just edit check it

Answer (score 0):

If you declare property as virtual, I suppose that EF is loading navigation property object as proxies (lazy loading). Lazy loading is turned off by making nav property non virtual.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx#eager